# Ubuntu Gnome 14.04: stop upgrading old kernel

Tags: upgrade, kernel

I recently upgraded the kernel in Ubuntu 14.04 from 3.13 to 3.16. But the Updater (or apt) keeps insisting on upgrading the 3.13 branch. How to stop this behavior? Is it safe to remove all 3.13 kernels?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove meta packages.

`sudo apt-get remove linux-image-generic linux-headers-generic`

You installed new 3.16 meta packages `linux-image-generic-lts-utopic` and `linux-headers-generic-lts-utopic` that will upgrade 3.16.